# Error at every reload of Uvicorn + FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I get this error every time I save. Besides, it takes a while to recharge.

I have tried several versions of Python with the same result.
I try to execute the example code.

Can somebody help me?

```
INFO:     Application startup complete.
WARNING:  WatchFiles detected changes in 'main.py'. Reloading...
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [5164]
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 685, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\x\Documents\GitHub\bravissimo\.env\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 78, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\x\Documents\GitHub\bravissimo\.env\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 123, in run
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
KeyboardInterrupt
INFO:     Started server process [14264]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

Package           Version

---

annotated-types   0.6.0
anyio             4.3.0
click             8.1.7
colorama          0.4.6
fastapi           0.110.0
h11               0.14.0
httptools         0.6.1
idna              3.6
pip               24.0
pydantic          2.6.4
pydantic_core     2.16.3
python-dotenv     1.0.1
PyYAML            6.0.1
sniffio           1.3.1
starlette         0.36.3
typing_extensions 4.10.0
uvicorn           0.29.0
watchfiles        0.21.0
websockets        12.0
Python 3.12.2

Comment: Downgraded to v0.21.1, and reloading works instantly again.